# Exception for making connection to Informix

Tags: c#, informix

I am getting '$exception.Message threw an exception of type System.IO.IOException for `IfxConnection.Open()`'.

This is the code

```
 string conn = "Service=ms7;Database=testdb;Server=test2000;UserID=test123;Password=test123";
 IfxConnection myconnection = new IfxConnection(conn);
 myconnection.Open();
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the Informix server using DB-Access?  Do you have any working C# code that connects to the server?  Is there any more information in the exception messages?  Is there a way to check the the `new IfxConnection` worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the connection string. It was the version of the IBM.Data.Informix.dll.
I downloaded the one with 2.90.6.0